# ForkJoinPool, Phaser and managed blocking: to what extent do they works against deadlocks?

Tags: java, java-8, phaser, forkjoinpool

This little code snippet never finishes on jdk8u45, and used to finish properly on jdk8u20:

```
public class TestForkJoinPool {

    final static ExecutorService pool = Executors.newWorkStealingPool(8);
    private static volatile long consumedCPU = System.nanoTime();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final int numParties = 100;
        final Phaser p = new Phaser(1);
        final Runnable r = () -> {
            p.register();
            p.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
            p.arriveAndDeregister();
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < numParties; ++i) {
            consumeCPU(1000000);
            pool.submit(r);
        }

        while (p.getArrivedParties() != numParties) {}
    }

    static void consumeCPU(long tokens) {
        // Taken from JMH blackhole
        long t = consumedCPU;
        for (long i = tokens; i > 0; i--) {
            t += (t * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL + i) & (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFL);
        }
        if (t == 42) {
            consumedCPU += t;
        }
    }
}
```

The [doc of phaser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) states that

> Phasers may also be used by tasks executing in a ForkJoinPool, which will ensure sufficient parallelism to execute tasks when others are blocked waiting for a phase to advance.

However the [javadoc of ForkjoinPool#mangedBlock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#managedBlock-java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.ManagedBlocker-) states:

> If running in a ForkJoinPool, the pool may first be expanded to ensure sufficient parallelism

Only a may there. So I am not sure whether or not this is a bug, or just bad code that is not relying on the contract of the Phaser/ForkJoinPool: how hard does the contract of the combination Phaser/ForkJoinPool works to prevent deadlocks?

---

My config:

1. Linux adc 3.14.27-100.fc19.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 17 19:36:34 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
2. 8 cores i7

Comment: Filed: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8080939

Comment: @AlekseyShipilev Maybe more insights on the issue: If I remove the comsumeCpu() part, or lower the number of tokens, the test finishes properly. Same thing if I breakpoint in ForkJoinPool#tryCompensate and step manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem comes from a change in the ForkJoinPool code between JDK 8u20 and 8u45.

In u20, ForkJoin threads were always alive for at least 200 milliseconds (see ForkJoinPool.FAST_IDLE_TIMEOUT) before being reclaimed.

In u45, once the ForkJoinPool has reached its target parallelism plus 2 extra threads, threads will die as soon as they run out of work without waiting.
You can see this change in the the awaitWork method in ForkJoinPool.java (line 1810):

```
    int t = (short)(c >>> TC_SHIFT);  // shrink excess spares
    if (t > 2 && U.compareAndSwapLong(this, CTL, c, prevctl))
        return false;
```

Your program uses Phasers tasks to create extra workers. Each task spawns a new compensating worker that is meant to pick up the next submitted task. 
However, once you reach the target parallelism + 2, the compensating worker dies immediately without waiting and does not have a chance to pick up the task that will be submitted immediately afterwards.

I hope this helps.